# How does MongoDB C# Driver's serverSelectionTimeout, SocketTimeout, ConnectTimeout Work?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My goal was to reduce the time it takes until the application stops to try connecting to a server.
This is the solution I am now using:
(It works, but I want to understand more in detail how)

```
MongoClientSettings clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings()
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, port),
    ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
    {
        //The "Normal" Timeout settings are for something different. This one here really is relevant when it is about
        //how long it takes until we stop, when we cannot connect to the MongoDB Instance
        //https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1018, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1231
        builder.ConfigureCluster(settings => settings.With(serverSelectionTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
    }
};
```

I do not understand exactly what `SocketTimeout` and `ConnectTimeout` is then used for.

If I make those settings e.g. to 3 seconds, it actually would not make sense for the driver to wait longer then, since it is not expected that anything good can happen after the socket had a timeout?

My theory is that Connect and SocketTimeout affect how long it takes until the the connect to a single server waits, while serverSelectionTimeout is the timeout for the overall process? Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

You might see here in [`ClusterRegistry.cs`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/ClusterRegistry.cs#L141) that `ConnectTimeout` is passed to `TcpStreamSettings.ConnectTimeout`, while `SocketTimeout` is passed to both `TcpStreamSettings.ReadTimeout` and `TcpStreamSettings.WriteTimeout`.

Then in [`TcpStreamFactory.cs`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Connections/TcpStreamFactory.cs#L68) you see how those `Read` and `Write` timeouts are used: they are used as `NetworkStream.ReadTimeout` and `NetworkStream.WriteTimeout`, when creating stream to read\write data from\to TCP connection.

Now, if we go to [documentation of NetworkStream.ReadTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk6w7hs8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we see there:

> This property affects only synchronous reads performed by calling the Read method. This property does not affect asynchronous reads performed by calling the `BeginRead` method.

But in *Mongo* driver, those network streams are read asynchronously, which means those timeouts do nothing. Same story with NetworkStream.WriteTimeout.

So long story short: `SocketTimeout` seems to have no effect at all and `ConnectTimeout` on the other hand is used when doing TCP connection. How exactly it happens you can see in [`TcpStreamFactory.cs`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Connections/TcpStreamFactory.cs).